Evaluating $\int\arctan\left(x!\right)\mathrm dx$
What I've done so far:
By parts:
$$\int\arctan\left(x!\right)\mathrm dx=x\arctan(x!)-\int\frac{\Gamma(x+1)\psi(x+1)}{1+(x!)^2}\mathrm dx$$
I cannot get any further than this.
Does anyone know any mathematical methods that can be used to evaluate the integral?

It seems that the anti-derivative is non-elementary. Wolfram Alpha gives the first few terms of the series expansion of the integral.

With a bit of heuristics
$$I=\int_0^t\arctan\left(x!\right)\,\mathrm dx\sim \frac \pi 2 t-2+\frac 1{t^2} $$
Edit
After @Gary's comment
$$I=\int_0^t\arctan\left(x!\right)\,\mathrm dx\sim \frac \pi 2 t-\frac{3 \pi }{5}+\frac{e^t\, t^{-(t+\frac{1}{2})}}{\sqrt{2
   \pi } \log (t)}+\epsilon$$

The constant is not $-2$ but rather $\int_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\arctan (x!) - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right){\rm d}x}  =  - 1.88106802498681 \ldots ,$.

@Gary. I know that. SInce i wrote $\sim$

If that constant is denoted by $C$, then then $$
\int_0^t {\arctan (x!){\rm d}x}  \sim \frac{\pi }{2}t + C + \frac{1}{{\Gamma (t + 1)\psi (t + 1)}}
$$
